# Insert new li element after id

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add an element after a specific element with an `id`

```
 <ul>
      <li>fred</li> 
      <li>wilma</li>
      <li id ="name">barny</li>
      <li> </li>
      <li> </li>
 </ul>
```

Insert betty after barny by specifying the `id` `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just find that element via [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId), create the new element via [`document.createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547), and then (this is the tricky bit) insert it by calling [`Element#insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) on the [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) of the one you want to insert after, specifying you reference element's [`nextSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-6AC54C2F) as the reference node.

E.g.:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("name");
var newElm = document.createElement("li");
newElm.innerHTML = "You probably want something here";
elm.parentNode.insertBefore(newElm, elm.nextSibling);
```

Note that this even works if your reference node is the last node in its parent. In that case, `nextSibling` will be `null`, and `insertBefore` knows what to do with that.

Comment: There is also a need to find the next element after `#name`, ignoring the text nodes...

Comment: @VisioN: I don't think you need to ignore text nodes, but I just added the `nextSibling` bit (doh!).

Comment: You're right. I thought spaces might ruin the concept somewhere in IE.

Comment: @VisioN: Ah, yes, IE. Very good point, well worth checking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function test()
    {

    $("#name").after("<li id='loremId' name='lorem' >lorem</li>")
    $("#loremId").after("<li id='ipsumId' name='ipsum' >ipsum</li>")
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <ul>
          <li>fred</li> 
          <li>wilma</li>
          <li id ="name">barny</li>
     </ul>



    <script>
    test();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```